# antlr return values as key-value

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, antlr3, antlrworks

I want to parse the sentence `"i am looking for a java developer from india"`.
The output i need is language=java and place=india

I created a grammar file as follows.

```
grammar Job;

eval returns [String value]
    :    output=jobExp {System.out.println($output.text); $value = $output.text;}
    ;


jobExp returns [String value]
    :    ind=indro whitespace var1=language ' developer from ' var2=place 
                            {
                            System.out.println($var1.text);
                            System.out.println($var2.text);
                            $value = $var1.text+$var2.text; }
    ;

indro
    :
    'i am looking for a'
    |
    'i am searching for a'
    ;

language :
    'java' | 'python' | 'cpp'
    ;

place :
    'india' | 'america' | 'africa'
    ;

whitespace :
    (' '|'\t')+
    ;
```

inside `jobExp` i am getting the values for `place` and `language`. And I am just returning only those two variables. But in `eval` i am getting the whole sentence(i am looking for a java developer from india). What should i need to get the exact matching output in `eval` ? Is it possible to get the output as `json` or `hashMap` in `antlr`?

My `java` class for testing the grammar as follows:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class JobTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("i am looking for a java developer from india" );
        JobLexer lexer = new JobLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        JobParser parser = new JobParser(tokens);
        System.out.println(parser.eval()); // print the value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `@header` block in your grammar to add it to the generated parser file.

```
grammar Job;

@header {
    import java.util.HashMap;
}
```

You can further on your grammar file use the `HashMap` class just as you're using `String`.

There's also the `@members` block to define private fields of the parser. You can check an example using both blocks to define an expression evaluator in [this tutorial](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Expression+evaluator).